# Magento 2 migration tables

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, migration

When we migrate the Magento1.x to Magento2.x what are the tables we can migrate using migration tool? And what are the tables need to migrate from the current version? can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Magento Core table can be migrated from M1 to M2 using **config.xml** of migration tool of your current magento 1 version (`dir>/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/ce-to-ee`) but you have to ignore third-party  module tables.

If you have added any custom column into core tables you can ignore that too using like below code:

```
<source>
  <field_rules>
    <ignore>
      <field>sales_flat_order.custom_column</field>
    </ignore>
```

**The migration consists of the following steps:**

1. Migrate Magento 1.x module structure to the structure recognized in Magento 2
2. Migrate Magento 1.x layout XML files to the format recognized in Magento 2
3. Migrate Magento 1.x config XML files to the format recognized in Magento 2
4. Migrate the PHP code in terms of how it interacts with the Magento framework, preserving the business logic

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. Many of my core tables has been overwritten